# Access Automatically find matches and link after flat file import

Tags: csv, ms-access, database-design, import

I'm building an Access Database, and I'm a database design rookie. I have two tables, we'll call them Parent and Child. These tables represent a one-to-many relationship in the direction that one Parent can have many children. This data comes to us in the form of a flat file that we import the initial parent-child relationship. Later, we manually add other child relationships to the parent as situations demand.

When I do the initial flat file import, I bring in a unique identifier that I place into both the parent and child. My understanding is this type of duplication is poor database design because it's duplicative. I want to avoid this if I can. I can't think of another way to draw the link.

The other question I have, is, it is my understanding that it is best to use the AutoNumber primary key to do any database references. 1. Am I just wrong here? 2. Is it okay to use the unique identifier that I bring in with the flat file? 3. If it is bad design to bring in the duplicative data, is there a way, during the import process, to draw this link automagically to the Primary Key (I already have a macro on this import process to tie it to a user form, adding to this macro is not an issue)?

The purpose of this:
There is a subform on the parent record that should list any related child records in the child record database.

Comment: 1) I have used non-autonumber fields as primary key; 2) see 1; 3) associating records with autonumber key generated during import requires post-processing using identifier comes with flat file - VBA is 'automagic'

Comment: You can choose to use autonumber, or often one will "make up" some value. When dealing with imported data, then often using your own PK creation is fine. The one advantage here is that these "one row" that is to be split up is at that time together as a single row - and thus you have this to your advantage - you KNOW that the data belongs to the two tables - it then becomes a question of how much code you want to write to split out that data to the two (or even more) correct related tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just imported the unique record to both the parent and the child and used that. It's working great. It changed how I built my manual new child record creation process, but it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier if you had provided a simple example.
If your data already contain IDs, example:

```
P:1,XX,YY
C:1,1,blah
C:1,2,fuh
P:2,zz,ww
C:2,1,doh
```

..then it would be next to impossible to match to autonumbering.

Either skip the ID completely, or if it's important, make the ID a different column and just use autonumber to make sure records are different.

So that master is

AutoID, PID, F1, F2,...

and child is

AutoID, ParentID, ChildID, FC1, FC2, ...

then match parent.PID onto child.ParentID.

If there is only ever 1 parent per child, you can set Parent.PID to "unique".